# Writing to Multiple Blank Pages with Hummus.js

Tags: node.js, hummus.js

I have a long column like content that is being written to the left half of a page (page 1) but is overflowing so I need to create page 2 and finish writing the content to page 2 before going back to page 1 and writing to the right-hand side.

I created code that will allow me to store the pages (page 1 and 2) in an array and also store the contexts in an array so that I can easily switch between the contexts I am writing to.

**However, the new pages I create are empty even though I am writing to their context**

Here is the function that gets called when I'm ready to create page 2 and write a test statement on it.

```
function createNewPage(){
      //Note all these variables are global, and hence I don't need to reinitialize them 

      if(lastPageNumber === 0 && currentPageNumber == 0){
          currentPageNumber++;
      }
      else{
          lastPageNumber++;
          currentPageNumber++;
      }
      //create a new page and store it in my array
      pagesArray[currentPageNumber] = pdfWriter.createPage(0, 0, eiReportPageWidth, eiReportPageHeight); 

      // create a new context and store it in my other array
      cxtArray[currentPageNumber] = pdfWriter.startPageContentContext(pagesArray[currentPageNumber]);

      //select the context I want to write to
      cxt = cxtArray[currentPageNumber];

      //I try writing to this new context but nothing happens and I get back a blank page

      cxt.writeText("Hello", 50, 400, fontOptions);
}

//Now that all elements are in place, write to the page

pagesArray.forEach(page =>{
    pdfWriter.writePage(page);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Explanation:

**First:**

You must need to specify `fontOption` properly. And I am hoping the same.

```
var arialFont = pdfWriter.getFontForFile('./arial.ttf');
var fontOptions = {font:arialFont,size:14,colorspace:'gray',color:0x00};
```

**Second:**

If, first is perfect then here is the issue.

```
if(lastPageNumber === 0 && currentPageNumber == 0){
  currentPageNumber++;
}
else{
  lastPageNumber++;
  currentPageNumber++;
}
```

You are maintaining an array `pagesArray[currentPageNumber]` and an array starts with `0`. But you always incremented by 1 when `currentPageNumber == 0`.

So your pagesArray seems:

```
[
  <1 empty item>,
  PDFPage {
    rotate: undefined,
    artBox: undefined,
    trimBox: undefined,
    bleedBox: undefined,
    cropBox: undefined,
    mediaBox: [ 0, 0, 595, 842 ]
  }
]
```

So, `pdfWriter.writePage(page)` will not able to write on `<1 empty item>`.

### Solution:

- Either you would have the first page already. (But you don't have)
- Assuming that you are creating fresh PDF. You need to start with `0`. Just use some loop to iterate `currentPageNumber` from 0 till `lastPageNumber`.

See working demo here https://repl.it/@hrdk108/Hardik-Shah-hummus

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but your snippet does not solve my problem. I made a small tweak as you can see here and it won't allow me to write to page 1 then 2 then 1 again.

https://repl.it/repls/DarkgreyOilyBookmarks

Comment: Apparently, you cannot keep multiple contexts open. So you should not be trying to go back to previous pages to write. You instead should plan your layout from the beginning and then write page by page only.